How to raise this power of the surd (fifth root)?
\[
    \sqrt[5]{
        \left[
            \left(
                \sqrt[3]{16+8\sqrt{5}} + \sqrt{6-2\sqrt{5}}
            \right)^{ \sqrt[3]{16+8\sqrt{5}} - \sqrt{6-2\sqrt{5}} }
        \right]^{\sqrt{5}}
    }.
\]

How to get from

to


I don't think there is any way to make that expression look good.  I woulod suggest using (...)^{1/5}.

The amsmath package provides the macros \uproot and \leftroot to fine-tune the placement of the optional root-number term.
To keep the square-root terms from becoming needlessly large, I'd also avoid autosizing the tall delimiters via \left and \right directives and, instead using \biggl/\biggr and \Biggl/Biggr instead. And, once you've settled on the overall verticl size, don't be shy about using \, and \! to fine-tune the horizontal placements.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \uproot and \leftroot macros

\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt[\uproot{20} 5]{ % <-- note the '\uproot{20}' directive
    \Biggl[ \!
    \biggl(\!
        \sqrt[\leftroot{-2} 3]{16+8\sqrt{5}} 
       +\sqrt{6-2\sqrt{5}}
        \,\biggr)^{%
        \!\!\! \sqrt[\leftroot{-2} 3]{16+8\sqrt{5}} 
              -\sqrt{6-2\sqrt{5}} }
    \,\Biggl]^{\!\sqrt{5}}
    } \,.
\]
\end{document}


Thanks. That will do just fine for my purpose.

@CasperYC - You're most welcome.
